Why can't I add more than 1 breakpoint in Google Apps Debugger
When I go into the Google apps debugger it only lets me run the 1 function that is selected at the top.  When I add additional breakpoints to the other functions and hit the play button it does not see those breakpoints. The process just ends. So what I really want is to walk through the debugger from start to finish.  This will allow me to enter the data that I need and to see all the variables that are set along the way. If I try to run the separate functions, some will fail because of the required variables and/or objects do not exist.
Regards,
JohnO
I added several breakpoints and all were ignored except the first one in the function that I selected.

If the other functions are called by the original function it will stop at those breakpoints when you are using debug mode,  Run mode never stops at breakpoints.  Breakpoints are only relevent to debug mode.

Next to the Run button you will see debug, when adding breakpoints use that to run the code and step in or step out to the breakpoints



Thank you for your response, however that is not the problem.  I can only debug 1 function at a time.  The one that I selected from the top.  Once that functiion completes the debugger ends.  When I put a second break in another function it never gets to that break.  I need multiple breaks in mutiple functions.  Is there a way to do that?

Gotcha!
let's say that you have

Depending the selected function the breakpoint will be used by the debugger, so your question is how to take both breakpoints within a single debug execution.
if the functions do not have chained calls or nested calls the breakpoints will be ignored as they should because the execution only cover the selected function
An easy workaround is  create a function like this and it will take all the breakpoints , I hope this helps


You should learn how to post and - format code as copiable text

for this it was needed to show the IDE screen with the code
